# Nodejs file download via client (client act as 'middleman' between server and file)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, upload, file-transfer

First off, I know this seems illogical when I could just send the download URL to the server. The issue with that is that user's can access these download links and so for those who can I need to be able to download it. I can't really explain why as I am under NDA.

I am trying to download a file from a URL via the client (browser) and stream the data directly to the server where the file is saved so the client essentially acts as a "middleman" and does not require the file to be downloaded to the client's machine.

I have been experimenting with "socket.io-stream" and "socket.io-file" but i am having a few issues with both. "socket.io-stream" allows me to upload a specific file from the client to the server but the uploaded file has a size of 0kb and doesn't have any examples on Github.

"socket.io-file" has examples, which I followed and currently have it setup so I can use an input tag to select a file to upload to the server successfully.

From what I can see the "socket.io-file" upload function takes a file object as the parameter.

So I have two questions really:

1. Is there a plugin for JS (Browser) & NodeJs (Server) that would allow me to do this?

   or
2. How can I create a File Object from an external url?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: updated question, sorry

Comment: Why have the client in the middle? Why not pass the URL to the backend, and have it download directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this is the end, using a chrome extension to download the file as a blob object, pass the object to the content script and then use socket.io-stream to upload it to the server.